# Custom locale in vis.js timeline using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am using vis.js timeline in a Vue.js project. Although it seems pretty easy to customize the locale using vanilla javascript (see [codepen](https://codepen.io/cassio-morales/pen/XWeByzQ?editors=1111) and [documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Localization)), I just can't get it done with Vue. I have already added moment.js and moment-with-locales-es6 to my project. Is this the right way to apply the locale to moment.js so it also applies to vis timeline?

This is my vue.js component:

```
<template>
    <div className="wrapper">
        <div id="visualization"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import {Timeline} from 'vis-timeline/standalone';
import tr from 'moment/locale/tr'
import moment from "moment-with-locales-es6";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    content: "1",
                    start: new Date(2021, 2, 23),
                    group: 0
                },
            options: {
                locale: "tr",
                locales: {
                    tr: {
                        current: "geçerli",
                        time: "kere",
                    },
                },
            },
            timeline: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.timeline = new Timeline(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        this.timeline.setOptions(this.options);
        this.timeline.setItems(this.items);
        moment.locale('tr')
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding this to my index.html file:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/tr.js'></script>
```

I am pretty sure there's a better solution for this...

Comment: Hello Cassio I am having the same issue by any chance did you figure out a better way to handle this?

Comment: I tried to apply locale to moment in different files and in different lifecycle hooks but with no luck. If you eventually find out how to solve this, please let me know